# Displaying a list on view which is passed through model

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

I have passed a list to the view through my controller.

**Code:**

```
model.put("ScheduleList", schedulelist);
        return new ModelAndView("EmployeeScheduleResult","message","Welcome "+(String)req.getSession().getAttribute("uname"));
```

The list has the following contents:

```
public class ScheduleList {
    Date date;
    String status;
    String color;
    //with setters ,getters and constructor. 
}
```

I want to print the list in such a way:

```css
.weekday{
background-color:blue;
}
.weekend{
background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>MONDAY</th>
  <th>TUESDAY</th>
  <th>WEDNESDAY</th>
  <th>THURSDAY</th>
  <th>FRIDAY</th>
  <th>SATURDAY</th>
  <th>SUNDAY</th>
 </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="weekday">2018-09-10</td>
        <td class="weekday">2018-09-11</td>
        <td class="weekday">2018-09-12</td>
        <td class="weekday">2018-09-13</td>
        <td class="weekday">2018-09-14</td>
        <td class="weekend">2018-09-15</td>
        <td class="weekend">2018-09-16</td>
      </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

The scheduleList would have the date, status and the color which would be displayed.

I thought of using the spring tags like

```
        <c:forEach items="${ScheduleList}" var="temp">
            <tr>
                <td>${temp.date}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

This will only result in the list displaying on the Monday column only. How would I display the list in the fashion listed above?

The problem is that I don't know how to dynamically add the css class to the td when the date is a weekday or weekend and also how to start my list from a particular day of the week. For Example, if my list starts with the date 2018-09-10 which is monday, then my table data should start with Monday(like the HTML code snippet above).

Can anyone guide me how to tackle this problem?

**EDIT:**

```
            <c:forEach items="${ScheduleList}" var="temp">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: ${temp.color};">${temp.date} 
                </td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

This code will add the color I had assigned in the list to the element but the problem of showing the list in horizontal fashion with monday dates coming on under monday and etc is still not resolved.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: I have added the css dynamically(see edit) but the issue for showing the list horizontally is still prelevant.

Comment: how many days would contain usually your ScheduleList list?

Comment: it would contain 30 days from the current date

Comment: ok, i am afraid to make it easier you will need to change your list in your controller to send N lists, one by week and order from Monday-Sunday or change your view and in place to use a table, use a div with 7 span elements inside so they relocate correctly alone.

Comment: I worked around the problem. Its not the best solution but it works. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by if and choose jstl tags.

**Code:**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>MONDAY</th>
            <th>TUESDAY</th>
            <th>WEDNESDAY</th>
            <th>THURSDAY</th>
            <th>FRIDAY</th>
            <th>SATURDAY</th>
            <th>SUNDAY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${startDay==0}">
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${startDay==6}">
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${startDay==5}">
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${startDay==4}">
                <td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${startDay==3}">
                <td></td><td></td>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${startDay==2}">
                <td></td>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${startDay==1}">
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
        <c:forEach items="${ScheduleList}" var="temp">
                <td style="background-color: ${temp.color};color:white;">${temp.date}</td>
                                <c:if test="${temp.dayOfWeek==0}">
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[image: The table data]

So I start a row and check whether what the starting date is in the week , i.e., 0 for sunday, 1 for monday and so on till saturday being the 6.

After checking it I created the consecutive `<td>` according to the day in week. This will result in the spaces which I needed to show in the table.

After that I start printing the dates but also check in the forEach if the given date is a sunday, if the date comes out to be a sunday then I close the previous row and open a new one.

I know this is a messy solution but could only think of this in the given time frame. If anyone else has another elegant solution I could use without changing the list I recieve from the controller or changing the db will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, i would say its not the cleanest solution, i would recommmend use div's, you only need to use a main container with 100% width and then then all children divs with a width of 100/7 so you dont need to create empty cells (TD) and the code would be cleaner and more maintenable

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I'll use div's, it'll be much easier.